# How do I effectively utilize the "build" step in Julia?

Tags: julia

Per the [Julia Docs](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/creating-packages/#Adding-a-build-step-to-the-package-1):

> The build step is executed the first time a package is installed or when explicitly invoked with build. A package is built by executing the file deps/build.jl.

Why would I want to make a `build.jl` file and how do I effectively utilize the benefits it allows for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically (historically) the build step and the `build.jl` file is used for downloading/installing binary dependencies with e.g. [`BinaryProvider`](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinaryProvider.jl) (or its predecessor [`BinDeps`](https://github.com/JuliaPackaging/BinDeps.jl))<sup>1</sup>. The build step can also be used to install configuration files. For example, [`IJulia`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) uses `build.jl` in order to install a Julia kernel for [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/).

If your package is pure Julia code you typically don't have a `build.jl` file since there is no need for it.

---

<sup>1</sup> With Julia 1.3 we have [`Artifacts`](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/dev/artifacts/) which is meant to replace the `BinaryProvider` workflow and make `build.jl` obsolete for the purpose of downloading and installing prebuilt binaries.